# Even after pip install pydotplus it says No module named 'pydotplus' what should be done?

Tags: python

```
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
from IPython.display import Image 
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import pydotplus
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydotplus'

Comment: Are you using any environment (e.g. conda) or just pip? Also, are you using any IDE (Spyder/Pycharm or maybe Jupyter Notebook)? Also, also, what operating system are you trying this on?

Comment: Sometimes `pip` installs modules where your Python script isn't looking. One obvious example might be if you're running Python 3 but `pip` is installing to `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. Double-check where `pip` installed `pydotplus`.

Comment: is the pip you are using associated with the same python that is running? eventually try pip3

Comment: Am using anaconda - jupyter notebook

Comment: Try uninstalling and running `conda install -c conda-forge pydotplus`

Comment: Am using python 3 but still it says the same. Tried pip3 as well. I don't understand what is wrong

Comment: Did conda install -c conda-forge pydotplus too. But even then it is not working

Comment: Try running `print(sys.executable)` in jupyter notebook and see if that does correctly point to the python interpreter that belongs to your anaconda version

Comment: I have the exact same problem on one of my PCs. It is fine on my work PC, but I get these errors on my home PC. Running and re-running the conda install tells me that pydotplus is already installed. However, the import statement fails. When I ran print(sys.executable) it showed me the correct python.exe (the one under Anaconda).

Answer (score 1):

```
python -m pip install pydotplus
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using conda, you should use conda installer instead of the pip one.
As per [documentation](https://github.com/conda-forge/pydotplus-feedstock):

> Installing pydotplus from the conda-forge channel can be achieved by adding conda-forge to your channels with:
>
> `conda config --add channels conda-forge`
>
> Once the conda-forge channel has been enabled, pydotplus can be installed with:
>
> `conda install pydotplus`

Comment: python -m pip install pydotplus    this worked for me. Thanks for all the help

Comment: @RanjithaVidyashankar can you provide it in form of the answer? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10:

Try running anaconda prompt as 'administrator', then use:

> conda install -c conda-forge pydotplus